# Bug: camel-sql - Could not resolve placeholder 'property.' in string value "sql query"

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, camel-sql

In **Camel 2.17.0**, camel sql component is not able to resolve property value using simple expression when externalized.

```
<route>
    <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1" />
    <setProperty propertyName="column_name">
        <simple>1234</simple>
    </setProperty>
    <!-- could nto resolve property - failed ->
    <to uri="sql:{{sql.query}}" />
    <!-- working ->
    <to uri="sql:classpath:sql.query.sql?dataSource=#DS" />
</route>
```

**External Properties file**:

```
 sql.query = insert into table (column_name) values (:#${property.column_name})
```

**Error Message**:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'property.column_name' in string value
>   "sql:insert into table (column_name) values
>   (:#${property.column_name})"

Comment: Okay try with newer version. Camel 2.17.0 is EOL.

Comment: this issue is observed even in camel 2.20.1 version 
Error Logs:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'property.column_name' in string value "sql:insert into table (column_name) values (:#${property.column_name})"

Comment: `to` endpoint does not support simple format. http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Well, I tried even using toD dynamic endpoint but same error

Comment: Check simple format, property.foo is deprecated. http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

Comment: insert query is updated :
insert into table (column_name) values (:#${exchangeProperty.column_name})

Error message:
Could not resolve placeholder 'exchangeProperty.column_name' in string value

Comment: Use `$simple{}` syntax, see TIP of this page: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/simple-language.adoc

Comment: Try setting `{{sql.query}}` in header or body and pass it to `to uri`

Comment: even {{sql.query}} did not work.
We need to add 
External Properties file:

 sql.query = insert into table (column_name) values (:#$simple{property.column_name})

:#$simple{property.value} - this will work
but document is not update as mentioned above